# Does ぶたれて mean being hit or hitting someone?

Tags: song-lyrics, passive-form

In the translations I can find of the verse below, the singer is the one doing the hitting. Why is that? My mind interprets this as a passive verb, indicating the singer is being struck? It's a very famous song.

> 夕焼け帰り道
> あなたに一度だけ
> **ぶたれて**泣いて帰ったの
> 寒い道ひとりで走った

If the translation is correct, meaning the singer is the performer of the action, a follow-up question would be: how would it be phrased if she was the one being hit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty clear that it means "being hit". The preceding あなたに  in the verse makes it clear that the person doing the hitting is the listener ("あなた"), not the speaker. Although the one receiving the hitting is not made explicit, it cannot be あなた, and the most reasonable assumption is that it is the speaker.

I'm not sure where you saw those translations in which the singer is the one doing the hitting, but [the one I found online](https://lyricstranslate.com/en/%E5%86%AC%E3%81%AE%E6%97%A5%E3%81%AE%E5%B8%B0%E3%82%8A%E9%81%93-fuyu-no-hi-no-kaeri-michi-winter-day-way-back-home.html) translates the part in question as "You hit me" (where "me" is the singer).

Comment: Thank you. I have mostly been using the translations by the blog Kimonobeat (https://kimonobeat.tumblr.com/post/171312445345/agnes-chan-lyrics-fuyu-no-hi-no-kaerimichi), which has struck me as being of good quality overall. Perhaps I have to reevaluate that opinion. I had disregarded the one on LyricsTranslate since a lot of phrasing seemed strange ("You always took me", "At the evening on the way back home, the loneliness shape was reflected" et cetera).